# "The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state" error in ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, image

I am getting the following errors "**GET http://localhost:60377/Icones/403 (Forbidden)"** and "**The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state**" when i try to load the image inside an ajax call success function. This question was asked before but for meteor project , and in my case it is an asp.net mvc project. This snippet

```
//Inside the ajax's call success function
   let iconName = JSON.parse(reponse);
   let image_element = document.createElement('img');
   let src = '/Icones/wifi.png';

   if (iconName !== 'default.png' && iconName !== null) {

       src = '/Icones/' +iconName';

   }
   image_element.setAttribute('src', src);
   let wifiClient = new fabric.Image(image_element);
   canvasFabric.add(wifiClient); //FabricJS canvas
```

I would appreciate any help.